# Form POST from WordPress Menu Item

Tags: wordpress, http-post

I want to be able to POST to an external URL when a user clicks a link (menu item) in a WordPress menu.

I've tried adding the required parameters to the URL of a custom menu item, but unfortunatley the external site requires the data to be submitted via POST rather than a GET.

Has anyone solved this problem before or know of any plugins that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.

I added a `form` to the top of the page with hidden fields corresponding to the data I wanted to POST. So in header.php straight after the opening body element:

```
<form id="postform" action="..." method="post" target="_blank">                
  <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="value1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="value2" />
  ...
</form>
```

Then I defined a Custom Menu Item with a URL of '#' and a CSS class of 'submitform'.

Finally, I added some JavaScript to the head in header.php to submit the form when the menu item link is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() 
  { 
    jQuery('.submitform').click(function() 
    {
      jQuery('#postform').submit();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I guess ideally an id would be assigned to the anchor created via the Custom Menu Item. However, WordPress doesn't appear to allow that and actually using a class has meant I can have links in both a header and footer menu with the same class and hence both submitting the form.